# Get Rank (Position) of Single Student Based on Total Score

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I would like to display the "rank" or "position" of a single student based on the total score of all subjects.

For example, if a student has the highest total score of 99, it should return a rank of 1st.
Another student with 92 should return 2nd.
If two students have the same score of 90, they should return 3rd position.

I don't want them to be in a table, just a single display.

This is my query
Model:

```
 public function GetClassPosition($student_id, $session_id, $section_id, $class_id) 
    {
        $this->db->order_by('tot_score', 'DESC');
        $this->db->select_sum('tot_score');
        $this->db->where('student_id', $subject_id);
        $this->db->where('session_id', $session_id);
        $this->db->where('section_id', $section_id);
        $this->db->where('class_id', $class_id);
        $data = $this->db->get('scores_primary'); 
    }
```

Controller:

```
 public function GetClassPosition($student_id, $session_id, $section_id, $class_id)
    {
  $data = $this->primary_model->GetClassPosition($student_id, $session_id, $section_id, $class_id); 
        return $data->tot_score;
    }
```

ordinal:

```
 function mtordinal($number) 
      {
        $ends = array('TH','ST','ND','RD','TH','TH','TH','TH','TH','TH');
        if ((($number % 100) >= 11) && (($number%100) <= 13))
            return $number. 'th';
        else
            return $number. $ends[$number % 10];
    }
```

To display it

View:

```
 <?php
$scores2 = $CI->GetClassPosition($value->$student_id, $value->session_id, $value->section_id, $value->class_id); 
$scores = array_column($scores2, 'tot_score');
$pos = array_search($value->tot_score, $scores);
$number = $pos + 1;
echo $CI->ordinal($number);
?>
```

Obviously, this brings out the result in a list form. How do I display the positions just for each student?

Comment: Show a sample data of how  ' echo $CI->ordinal($number) ' looks like...

Comment: It displays like this - 1st, 2nd, 13th etc